# ReactJS , setState issue onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, state

**in my child component I set input with onChange:**

```
<input onChange={this.handlePlaylistTermChange} defaultValue={'New Playlist'}/>
```

**which then sets the state of what the user has put in the input**

```
handlePlaylistTermChange(e){
    this.setState({playlistName: e.target.value });
```

then when the button is clicked I pass that value to a method that uses props to call the parent class method that takes in that state when the button is clicked

```
save() {
        if (this.state.playlistName === null || this.state.playlistName === "") {
            this.props.onSave('New Playlist') ;
        } else {
            this.props.onSave(this.state.playlistName);
        }
    }
```

which calls in the parent class:

```
savePlaylist(name) {
        let trackUrIs = [];

        console.log(name);
        let playlist =this.state.playlistTracks;

        playlist.forEach(track =>{
            trackUrIs.push(track.URI);

        });
        console.log( "passed in name"+ name);
        console.log(trackUrIs);

        Spotify.savePlaylist(trackUrIs,name);


        console.log('whats happening here?' + this.state.playlistName);
        this.setState({playlistTracks: []});
        this.setState({playlistName: ''});
```

This all works great except I need the Playlist name value to change back to "new playlist" but no matter what I seem to do the value that happened on the onChange remains. I have tried resetting the state in the child and passing that up to the parent and no matter what I cant get the onchange value to reset to "new playlist" after the save button has been clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DefaultValue` is only assigned to the input at the time of mounting and cannot be updated with a change, you should rather use a **`controlled input`** and set the value based on the state and in order to define a `defaultValue`, initialise it in `state`

```
state={
   playList: 'New Playlist'
}

<input onChange={this.handlePlaylistTermChange} value={this.state.playList}/>
```

Now `onChange` of the input field, you can update the playList state to reflect the updated value in input

```
handlePlaylistTermChange =(e) => {
    this.setState({playList: e.target.value});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { clickedItem: "show here..." };
    this.ItemClick = this.ItemClick .bind(this);        
}
ItemClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({ clickedItem: e.target.value});
}
```